# Cant figure out operators in php statement

Tags: php, operators

I need to edit a function, but I cant figure out what the ? and the : false mean in the return statement. I think the : is an OR but the ? I dont know.

`public function hasPermission($name)
{
return $this->getVjGuardADUser() ? $this->getVjGuardADUser()->hasPermission($name) : false;
}`

Anyone that can clear this up for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is PHP's [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). It's like a shorthand for if/else expressions.

Your expanded code could look like so:

```
public function hasPermission($name)
{ 
    if ($this->getVjGuardADUser()) {
        return $this->getVjGuardADUser()->hasPermission($name)
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Some sample-code from php.net:

```
// Example usage for: Ternary Operator
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];

// The above is identical to this if/else statement
if (empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = 'default';
} else {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems like a good operator to know, currently I have lots of those "expanded" if statements in my own code. Nice to know you can "clean" that up using this operator.

Comment: I really wish they would approve the ifsetor()-operator (http://wiki.php.net/rfc/ifsetor).

Answer (score 5):

It's the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), a simple oneliner if then construct.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ternary operator. It's documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

It's a short form for:

```
public function hasPermission($name) {
    if ($this->getVjGuardADUser()) {
        return $this->getVjGuardADUser()->hasPermission($name)
    } else {}
        return false;
    }
}
```

I recommend the more verbose style for conditional statements for better readability, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

```
variable = predicate ? /* predicate is true */ : /* predicate is false */;
```

In your code, it's a shorthand form of the following:

```
if($this->getVjGuardADUser())
    return $this->getVjGuardADUser()->hasPermission($name);
else
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a ternaire expression.

You can replace this by:

```
if ($this->getVjGuardADUser())
 return $this->getVjGuardADUser()->hasPermission($name);
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a ternaire  operator. Read more about it here:

- http://www.lizjamieson.co.uk/2007/08/20/short-if-statement-in-php/
- http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/76/ternary-php-short-hand-ifelse-statement/